# In python/django best way to create a list of objects method output

Tags: python, django, list

I have this code:

```
objects = Object.objects.all()

datalist = list()
    for object in objects:
        datalist.append(object.data())

return datalist
```

Is there any better way to create this datalist? There is the `values_list()` method for queryset, but it only works with object fields and not with methods.

So I wonder, if there is any better pythonic way that can create the `datalist` maybe in a single line rather in 3 lines?

Comment: What does `.data()` do here?

Comment: `datalist = [o.data() for o in objects]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *list comprehension*:

```
return [object.data() for object in Object.objects.all()]
```

or with a combination of `map` and `list`:

```
return list(map(Object.data, Object.objects.all()))
```

But it is not really clear to me what `.data()` is doing here, and thus there might be better (faster, more elegant, etc.) ways to do the same thing.

Comment: `data()` returns "some" data of the object in an api friendly format, so I could rephrase it as apidata or something like that. Because its an external API I need to reformat the object data. Maybe there is a much better way to deal with this...